CK editor primeng
Anybody know if is any way to to make CK editor create primeng textarea element instead of a simple div that is doing know? I use the API tag name but then CK editor don't even work, I use CKeditor 41, also I use angular
I try to create primeng element instead of default div that CKeditor create
